# Boton de eliminar en ListView Android

Tags: android, listview

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he creado una lista personalizada usando `simpleCursorAdapter`
comúnmente accedía a los elementos dando clic sobre ellos de la siguiente forma:

```
Listado = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListaAgregados);
Listado.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     TextView codigo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mostrarCodigo);
     Log.d("ElementoSeleccionado>",codigo.getText.toString);


          }
        });
```

los elementos son de la base de datos `Sqlite` elimino elementos de la siguiente forma:

```
basededatos.Eliminar(codigo); //codigo del elemento seleccionado.
```

entonces ¿como seria el codigo que al dar clic en el boton me elimine?

Comment: Buena pregunta, anteriormente se usaba   para eliminar el elemento del cursor: dba.remove(_id);
 y
    cursor.requery(); para obtener nuevamente los datos....ahora es obsoleto este método. Veamos si alguièn puede responder.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que estás solicitando, es decir, no se si te refieres que al darle a un elemento del listview este borre esa fila de datos de la base de datos sqlite o que al darle click a ese elemento este se borre del listview. Si pudieras explicarlo un poco mejor te lo agradeceria.

Comment: para resolver y hacerlo facil esto, **al darle clic en el boton x que me muestre en un Toast el primer elemento de esa fila** me explico?

Comment: Supongo q estás utilizando un Modelo entonces solo traerías el id del Modelo.. traerías al `modelo.getId()` por la posición en la q te encuentras

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta, te refieres a ¿dar click a un view de la lista y que elimine el item?. Yo lo que haria seria crear una clase adapter que herede de BaseAdapter y ahí puedes jugar con los botones obteniendo la posición. Un ejemplo [aquí](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-a-BaseAdapter-with-ListView)

Answer (score 1):

La verdad es que no estoy seguro de si es esto lo que necesitas pero yo por si acaso te lo digo.

Cuando haces click en un elemento del listview ya obtienes su posicion, entonces sabiendo esta posicion puedes consultar en el adapter donde cargas los datos y recuperar esa posicion y asi ya sabes que datos hay en esa fila. Algo asi:

```
Listado = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListaAgregados);
Listado.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     Object o = Listado.getItemAtPosition(position);
     String str=(String)o;//Esto suponiendo que la primera fila fuera una cadena string
     }
});
```

Ahi puedes ver como recuperar daros de un listview al hacer click en un elemento del mismo. En este caso recuperariamos un String suponiendo que ese fuera el tipo de datos de tu listView, de lo contrario podrias hacer algo asi:

```
ElTipoDeDatosEmpleado datos = Listado.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Espero haberte ayudado o dado una idea de lo que necesitas hacer.

Saludos.

Comment: El OP esta usando simpleCursorAdapter por lo tanto los datos se encuentran en un cursor.

Comment: pero no es clic en la lista. es programacion para el boton